# python to auto fill in import text in open office

Tags: python, openoffice.org

[image: Import Text]

(character set ,seperator options, and Fields in Apache Open Office)

The original file I have is a csv file. I want to **change the character set ,seperator options, and Fields** using python code and save it into an excel file. Is it possible to auto fill in these options? Or else what language can I use to automate this action? ( I cant do this in excel because excel will delete some of my special character.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **xlsxwriter** module to make XLSX files: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html

Assume you have a CSV file with encoding CP1251 and you want to get XLSX file with encoding UTF8. Here is how it can be done:

```
import xlsxwriter # pip3 install xlsxwriter

# get data from the csv file with non utf8 encoding
with open('data_cp1251.csv', 'r', encoding='cp1251') as f:
    data = f.read()

# convert the data into 2d array
table = [row.split(",") for row in data.split("\n")]

# create xlsx file (utf8 encoding by default)
ss = xlsxwriter.Workbook('data.xlsx')
s = ss.add_worksheet()

# fill the xlsx file with the 2d array
for row_num, row in enumerate(table):
    for col_num, cell in enumerate(row):
        s.write(row_num, col_num, cell)

ss.close() # here you get the 'data.xlsx' file
```

For simply cases it works even if the source CSV file has tab `\t` separators. But it's need to test on your real data.

And as far as I can tell all fields in the new xlsx file are 'text fields' by default. You can change their formats any time, see here: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#format